# Sum of all textboxes using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im adding all textboxes values on blur call. I give some number in one textbox.  When it tries to add value of the other textbox value, it throws NaN.

Here is my code

```js
function sumOfIncome() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.add').each(function() {
    sum += parseInt(this.value);
    console.log(sum)
  });
  $('#netPay').val(sum);
}
$('.add').blur(function() {
  sumOfIncome();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="DA" class="col-form-label">DA</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="number" class="form-control add" id="da" placeholder="DA">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="HRA" class="col-form-label">HRA</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="number" class="form-control add" id="hra" placeholder="HRA">
  </div>
</div>
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that all of the values of `this.value` are parse-able integer numbers? The way your code is written, what happens if you fill in one and the other is still blank?

Comment: Works just fine when you have numbers in the fields: https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/217mmkhc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to change your sum line to `sum += parseInt(this.value) || 0;`. This way, if the field is empty and returns a [*falsey*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value like `NaN`, it will instead use `0`.

```js
function sumOfIncome() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.add').each(function() {
    sum += parseInt(this.value) || 0;
    console.log(sum)
  });
  $('#netPay').val(sum);
}
$('.add').blur(function() {
  sumOfIncome();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="DA" class="col-form-label">DA</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="number" class="form-control add" id="da" placeholder="DA">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="HRA" class="col-form-label">HRA</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="number" class="form-control add" id="hra" placeholder="HRA">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Downvoter care?? I didn't get it. Its working anyways. :)

Comment: @SyedSha Someone had downvoted all of the answers without leaving feedback on any of them. I was just gently asking them to leave some constructive criticism.

Comment: @j08691..Got it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this `$.isNumeric()` [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ojtpt7p/#&togetherjs=L8f0812r7U):

Html:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-3"><label for="DA" class="col-form-label">DA</label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">   <input type="number" class="form-control add" id="da" placeholder="DA">
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-3"><label for="HRA" class="col-form-label">HRA</label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">   <input type="number" class="form-control add" id="hra" placeholder="HRA">
        </div>
</div>
<div id="netPay">

</div>
```

Jquery:

```
function sumOfIncome() {
   var sum = 0;
   $('.add').each(function(){
   var val = $(this).val();
   if($.isNumeric(val))
   {
       sum += parseInt(val);
       console.log(sum)
   }
   });
   $('#netPay').text(sum);
  }

  $('.add').blur(function(){
    sumOfIncome();
  });
```